# Relacionamento N para N e Um para N com CodeFirst Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, dataannotations

Como posso fazer o relacionamento N para N e Um para N utilizando Data Annotations?

Por exemplo:

Uma movimentação de venda possui um usuário, e um usuário pode ter várias movimentações.

Esta mesma movimentação de venda possui vários produtos, e cada produto pode estar em várias movimentações.

Como posso realizar este mapeamento utilizando Data Annotation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Outra proposta***

<sub>**Peço desculpas, mas, se você tivesse colocado as entidades suas pelo menos a gente poderia simular, então, eu fiz um exemplo que possui praticamente a mesma lógica e você pode implementar no seu que está dando alguns erros.**</sub>

**1)** *N para M (muitos para muitos)*.

***Explicação:*** onde um Livro pode ter vários Autores e um Autor pode estar em vários Livros.

```cs
[Table("Autor")]
public class Autor
{
    public Autor()
    {
        this.Livros = new HashSet<Livro>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AutorId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }

}

[Table("Livro")]
public class Livro
{

    public Livro()
    {
        this.Autores = new HashSet<Autor>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LivroId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public String Titulo { get; set; }

    public int TipoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TipoId")]
    public virtual Tipo Tipo { get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Autor> Autores { get; set; }
}
```

Perceba que nesse tipo só é colocado uma `ICollection` Autores dentro de Livro e `ICollection` Livros dentro de Autor, não precisando criar um Entidade a mais (no caso ela será a relação). Nas próprias coleções serão feitas as operações de `Add` (Adicionar) e `Remove` (Remover), na tabela intermediária AutorLivro, onde a mesma possui as chaves de Autor e Livro.

*Olha como ficaria a proposta com esses modelos gerados no banco.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2)** 1 para N (um para muitos)

***Explicação:*** onde um Livro possui um Tipo e um Tipo pode possuir vários livros

```cs
[Table("Tipo")]
public class Tipo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TipoId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TipoId")]
    public ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

Dentro de Livro possui um campo TipoId `ForeignKey` para a entidade Tipo e dentro de Tipo uma Collection de Livros, isso força o relacionamento entre essas entidades.

*Modelo Final proposto:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contexto:

Nesse item que é a classe que herda de `DbContext`, foram colocados 3 entidades (`Autor`, `Livro` e `Tipo`), e no `OnModelCreating`, eu forcei uma configuração na relação `N` para `M` (*não obrigatória*), mas, para mim essencial para que eu fale para o modelo como é a relação e o nome da Tabela, se você deixar a cargo do *Framework* ele gera também mas, com nomenclatura própria.

```cs
public class Db: DbContext
{
    public Db()
        :base("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CBOLayout;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha") { }

    public DbSet<Livro> Livro { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Autor> Autor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tipo> Tipo { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Autor>()
            .HasMany<Livro>(x=>x.Livros)
            .WithMany(x => x.Autores)
            .Map(x => 
            {
                x.ToTable("AutorLivro");
                x.MapLeftKey("AutorId");
                x.MapRightKey("LivroId");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

***Configurações:***

- `[Table("nome_da_tabela")]`: indica o nome da tabela que faz referência essa Entidade.
- `[Key]`: indica a `Primary Key` da sua tabela
- `[Required]`: não pode conter valores nulos, deve ser preenchido.
- `[MaxLength]`: tamanho do campo definido na base de dados, exemplo: `nvarchar(100)`.
- `[ForeignKey]`: indica a chave estrangeira.
- `[DatabaseGenerated]`: com essa configuração pode definir o auto incremento desse campo.

Rodando o Migrations

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class newBanco : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Autor",
            c => new
                {
                    AutorId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Nome = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.AutorId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Livro",
            c => new
                {
                    LivroId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Titulo = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    TipoId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.LivroId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Tipo", t => t.TipoId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.TipoId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Tipo",
            c => new
                {
                    TipoId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Descricao = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.TipoId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AutorLivro",
            c => new
                {
                    AutorId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LivroId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.AutorId, t.LivroId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Autor", t => t.AutorId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Livro", t => t.LivroId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AutorId)
            .Index(t => t.LivroId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AutorLivro", "LivroId", "dbo.Livro");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AutorLivro", "AutorId", "dbo.Autor");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Livro", "TipoId", "dbo.Tipo");
        DropIndex("dbo.AutorLivro", new[] { "LivroId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AutorLivro", new[] { "AutorId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Livro", new[] { "TipoId" });
        DropTable("dbo.AutorLivro");
        DropTable("dbo.Tipo");
        DropTable("dbo.Livro");
        DropTable("dbo.Autor");
    }
}
```

Referências:

- [DataAnnotation in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx)
- [Namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [ForeignKeyAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Part 6: Using Data Annotations for Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

Comment: Harry, sua resposta foi excelente e me esclareceu muitas duvidas, mas qual é a finalidade da implementação do DbMigration? A primeira vista, estou criando tabelas com algumas configurações, mas o entity já não faria isso automaticamente?

Comment: @Vinícius, quando se trabalha com `CodeFirst`, é mais que ideal, é meio obrigatório trabalhar com ele, porque, qualquer mudança em suas entidades são feitas por esse DbMigration. Você poderia abrir outro questionamento sobre isso, porque, é outra grande resposta :), qualquer dúvida tamos ai!

Answer (score 6):

Assim:

```
public class Movimentacao
{
    [Key]
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Movimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Não existe a necessidade de utilizar nenhuma Data Annotation para mapear as propriedades de coleção? Caso, por exemplo, eu queira que Movimentação tenha vários produtos, basta trocar a propriedade para um ICollection?

Comment: @Vinícius O Entity Framework intui várias coisas sozinho. Para este exemplo do `ICollection`, sim, não é necessário decorar com atributos porque é o padrão de declaração 1 pra N do Entity Framework.