# Relacionamento 1:N com EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Eu tenho uma tabela de unidades conforme abaixo:

```
public class Unity
{
 public int Id {get;set }
 public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class UsersRight
{
 public int Id {get;set }        
 public string Name{ get; set; }
 public int Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Cada usuário poderá ter acesso a 1 ou n unidades. 
Eu terei uma lista com os registros das unidades.

```
var userRight = new List<UsersRight>;
userRight = _DAL.UserRights(user);

var listUser = new List<Unity>; 

foreach (var item in userRight)
{ 
  listUser.add( new Unity(Name = item.Name, Id = item.Value));
}
```

Qual a maneira mais eficiente de fazer isto com EF? Estou usando ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você teria que criar uma tabela de ligação entre Usuario e Unidade, porque um usuario tem acessoa  varias Unidades e uma Unidade estaria ligado a vários usuários, correto ?!

Comment: O seu Caso me parece N:N que teria que ter uma tabela de relacionamento entre elas, por exemplo , 2 usuarios tem acesso a mesma  Unidade , mas caso não seja assim o usuario teria um ICollection de Unidades, veja este link onde mostra um relacionamento 1:N http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Olhe esta pergunta também : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22042/relacionamento-n-para-n-e-um-para-n-com-codefirst-data-annotations

Comment: Na verdade cada usuário pode ter 1 ou n unidades. E cada unidade pode ter vários usuários

Comment: Então essa Relação é N:N , você precisaria de uma tabela extra, fazendo essa ligação, qualquer coisa eu respondo explicando como seria isso com exemplos.

Comment: Preciso também da sua classe que deriva `IdentityUser`.

Comment: Eu vou receber os dados do usuario logado com a relação de Claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso com uma `Unidade` pode ter vários `Usuarios` e um `Usuario` por ter varias `Unidade`, caracteriza um relacionamento N:N, o que no caso teria que ser feito com uma tabela extra fazendo a relação entre as duas.

Exemplo :

> Tabela Unidade

```
    public class Unity
{
 public int UnityId {get;set }
 public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

> Tabela Usuario

```
    public class UsersRight
{
 public int UsersRightId {get;set }        
 public string Name{ get; set; }
 public int Value{ get; set; }
}
```

> Está e a tabela de ligação entre as duas tabelas :

```
    public class UserUnitty
{
     public int UsersRightId {get;set }
     public int UnityId{ get; set; }

     public virtual UsersRight UsersRight{get;set;}
     public virtual Unity Unity{get;set;}

}
```

Considerações :

- Na tabela UserUnity, usa-se o `virtual`, o modificador `virtual` é utilizado pelo EF para fazer o Lazy Loading, que precisa criar instâncias de proxy que serão substituídas nessas propriedades virtuais. No caso quando você fizer uma query essas classes não estarão preenchidas.
- Eu usei o `UnityId` e `UserRightId` para não usar o `DataAnnotations`, mas caso queira manter como o orignal você pode apenas usar o `DataAnnotations` para especificar a qual tabela pertence aquela`ForeingKey`.

Comment: Willian, eu vou ter que usar o DataAnnotations, porque vou armazenar cada unidade no claims do usuário. Aí não quero alterar a estrutura das tabelas do Identity.

Comment: @b3r3ch1t Você tem que dizer que vai usar o ASP.NET Identity porque isso muda a resposta inteira.

Comment: Ixi, não tenho conhecimento sobre Asp.Net Identity para te ajudar, desculpa acabei me engando.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Não, não foi problema na sua resposta. O autor da pergunta não especificou direito a dúvida.

Comment: @WilliamCézar desculpa se te induzi a uma resposta errada. Cigano tem como vc mandar algum exemplo que me dê uma luz?

Comment: @b3r3ch1t Vou dar outra resposta e editar sua pergunta.